# not getting required return value

Tags: java, eclipse

if I use `double sum=0` instead of `int sum=0`, I get the expected answer (38.8) but when I use `int` I get 38.0 as answer. I want to know why is this happening since my return type is `double` so I should  not get automatically accurate decimal value output.

public class prg21 
{

```
    public static  double average(int...ar)
{
    int sum=0;

    for(int x:ar)
    {
        sum+=x;
    }

    return sum/ar.length;
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int []arr= {5,77,2,65,45};
    System.out.println("Average="+average(arr));
}
```

}

I expect 38.8 but I get 38.0

Comment: `return sum/(double)ar.length;`. What your are currently doing is returning the int result of `sum/ar.length` (which is round) casted to double by the return type.

Comment: I recommend you to learn about variables and what each one of them does

Answer (score 1):

int datatype will drop any decimal value

you get 38.0 because the expression is saved into an int, dropping decimals and making it 38, then it's returned as a double so it's converted to 38.0